# Android webview wont consistently open to last-scroll location

Tags: javascript, android, webview

I have an Android app that uses a KitKat-level WebView to display documents (primarily as an e-reader which consumes HTML files). When a user opens a document within the app (and thus the webview is thus newly instantiated for that document) I want to scroll to the last known cursor location within the document, so that the user can pick up reading where they left off. Obviously I retain and persist the cursor location indepedently of the webview to allow such scrolling when I first open up the document.

PROBLEM:
When the document first opens, I can see the initial highlighting of the last known location (cursor) in my javascript document, but then in perhaps 50% of the cases I've seen the document somehow scrolls back to the top and so the cursor location is no longer shown. How and why it scrolls back to the top in these cases is a mystery to me (I dont believe I programatically make it scroll back to the top in any way).

NOTES:
To achieve the scrolling within the webview I'm using a javascript function which is invoked from my webview fragment (via webview.loadUrl) once the webview has signalled it has loaded and ready to use. This is the callback from the document view fragment to the webview:

```html
 @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) @SuppressLint("ClickableViewAccessibility") @Override
 public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
 {  
  View mainView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.document_webview_reader, container, false);
  getReaderActivity().setFooterLocationBarValues(mainView);
  
  mWebviewLoading = true;
  final WebView webview = (WebView) mainView.findViewById(R.id.document_webReader_webView);
  webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
  webview.getSettings().setAllowFileAccessFromFileURLs(true); 
  webview.getSettings().setAllowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs(true);
  webview.setScrollBarStyle(View.SCROLLBARS_INSIDE_OVERLAY);
  webview.setBackgroundColor(0);
  webview.setBackgroundColor(Color.LTGRAY);
  
  if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) 
  {
      WebView.setWebContentsDebuggingEnabled(true);
  }
  
  mJsInterface = new JsCall();
  webview.addJavascriptInterface(mJsInterface, mJsInterface.getInterfaceName());
  
  webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient()
  {   
   public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url)
   {
    drawInitialCursor(getDocument().getCursorRange());      
   }
  });
  

 private void drawInitialCursor(final WordRange range)
 {
  if( getReaderActivity().activityIsPaused() ) return;
     
  getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable()
  {
   
   @Override
   public void run()
   {
    Log.d(ReaderApplication.VDREADER_TAG,"highlighting initial range");
    WordRange currentFragmentRange = mTextFragmentRanges.get(mCurrentTextFragmentIndex);
    int relativeLocation = range.getLocation() - currentFragmentRange.getStartRange();
    WordRange rangeInCurrentFragment = new WordRange(relativeLocation, range.getLength());
      
    WebView webview = (WebView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.document_webReader_webView);
    
    String applyString = String.format("javascript:highlightInitialRange(%d,%d,%d,%d)", 
      rangeInCurrentFragment.getStartRange(),rangeInCurrentFragment.getEndRange(), 
      mCurrentTextFragmentIndex,
      mCursorPositionSetting.ordinal());

    webview.loadUrl(applyString);
   }
  });
 }
```

The javascript for 'highlightInitialRange' is:

```js
function highlightInitialRange(start, end, elementIndex, cursorPagePositionSetting)
    {
        if( wordHighlightApplier == null ) {
            wordHighlightApplier = rangy.createClassApplier("voice-dream-spoken-word",
                { elementTagName: "vdword"}
            );
        }
        if( selRange == null ) {
            selRange = rangy.createRange();
        }

        wordHighlightApplier.undoToRange(selRange);
        var myNodelist = document.querySelectorAll(VD_cssSelector);

        selRange.selectCharacters(myNodelist[elementIndex], start, end);
        wordHighlightApplier.applyToRange(selRange);

        var wordCursor = document.getElementsByTagName("vdword");
        wordCursor[0].scrollIntoView(true);

    }
```

The above javascript essentially just finds the relevant range in the document (as a combination of element index and offset within that element), applies a highlight to it (via rangy) and then scrolls that highlighted element into view.

As I say I know this strategy generally works since I can always see it highlighting the correct location when the document is loaded and the webview is ready to use; but in ~50% of the times I run this, I see the cursor highlight briefly and then it disappears as the document is scrolled back to the top (assuming the cursor range is beyond the initial page of the document of course).

** I would post an image of the correct cursor highlight here but apparently I'm not reputable enough to allow such a triviality. **

QUESTION:
Am I missing something about webview document rendering here? I know everything is working correctly in terms of highlighting and the initial scroll-into-view for the highlighted element, and I'm only executing this highlighting code once the webview is fully loaded (notified via onPageFinished on the webview client). Is there something within the webview itself that is non-deterministically executing when the document is fully loaded to ensure that the document is displayed at its top-most scroll position?

*** RESOLVED BY OWNER

In hindsight the resolution to this problem was fairly obvious: I was using a 'wrapper' html document in which I loaded various JS libraries - JSQuery, Rangy etc, and within that I was using JSQuery to replace the document body with the 'real' html document I want to load/read. So from a HTML document point of view the loading was occurring in two phases:

1. Load the wrapper
2. Wrapper loads the real html document via $("body").load("")

Because of this two-phase loading, my app was seeing the Webview.onPageFinished event being fired - but this only signalled the loading of the wrapper html, not the full body. So all I needed to do was add an explicit call from my webview / javascript to the app once the JSQuery .load method had completed successfully:

```js
<body>
<script>
    $( "body" ).load( "%s", function( response, status, xhr )
    {
        if (status == "error")
        {
            var msg = "Sorry but there was an error: ";
            $("#error").html(msg + xhr.status + " " + xhr.statusText);
        }
        else
        {
            // append our line highlight div, floating
            var newDiv = $("<div id='vd-spoken-line' class='voice-dream-spoken-line'/>");
            $( "body" ).append(newDiv);

            notifyDocumentBodyLoaded();    <-- new callback to android app here
        }
    });
</script>
</body>
```

So then 'notifyDocumentBodyLoaded' executes the Android/java code formerly executed in the onPageFinished method, but only after the true document body has been loaded by JSQuery. That way the sequence of loading -> cursor drawing all happens in the correct order. Solved.

Comment: Resolved my own problem here - see updated question text.

Comment: Please consider posting an actual answer for sake of community and resolve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in updated question (adding this answer so I can resolve this):

In hindsight the resolution to this problem was fairly obvious: I was using a 'wrapper' html document in which I loaded various JS libraries - JSQuery, Rangy etc, and within that I was using JSQuery to replace the document body with the 'real' html document I want to load/read. So from a HTML document point of view the loading was occurring in two phases:

Load the wrapper
Wrapper loads the real html document via $("body").load("")
Because of this two-phase loading, my app was seeing the Webview.onPageFinished event being fired - but this only signalled the loading of the wrapper html, not the full body. So all I needed to do was add an explicit call from my webview / javascript to the app once the JSQuery .load method had completed successfully.